# remove "$" + sum.toFixed(2)

Tags: jquery, calculator

I am using the Pengoworks jquery calculator and do NOT want my sum to be rounded off.  ie: if the sum is 19.99 it is being rounded off to 19.

I "Think" it is in here: "$" + sum.toFixed(2)

Full code here: http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/calculation/calculation.plugin.htm

FULL CODE

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var bIsFirebugReady = (!!window.console && !!window.console.log);

    $(document).ready(
        function (){
            // update the plug-in version
            $("#idPluginVersion").text($.Calculation.version);

/*
// test precision
$("body").prepend("<div id='nn'></div>");
$("#nn").calc(
    // the equation to use for the calculation
    "qty * price",
    // define the variables used in the equation, these can be a jQuery object
    {
        qty: 23,
        price: 1.4
    }   
);
*/

/*          
            $.Calculation.setDefaults({
                onParseError: function(){
                    this.css("backgroundColor", "#cc0000")
                }
                , onParseClear: function (){
                    this.css("backgroundColor", "");
                }
            });
*/

            /*$("#qty_1082").keyup(function(){
                var dInput = $(this).val();
        alert(dInput);
            });*/

            /* ADDITION FOR VARIABLE DISCOUNTS - START */

            //bind check_discount on key up - MUST BE BEFORE recalc Function
            $("input[name^=qty_item_]").bind("keyup", check_discount);
            check_discount();
        /*  $( "input[name^=qty_item_]" ).each(function() {
                alert(this.name);
            });*/


            function check_discount(){
                $( "input[name^=qty_item_]" ).each(function() {
                    var input_value = $(this).val(); //get the value (amount of books) for the current input field being modified
                    var current_input_id = this.name; //get the name field for the current input field being modified   
                    var current_price=current_input_id.replace("qty","price"); //swap text to make it match the mathing price field


                    //Series of staments to determine the appropriate action
                    if(input_value < 10){
                        //alert("There is a minimum order of 10 books per title");
                        $("#"+current_price).text("$0.00"); //If between 50 and 99 adjust rate

                    } else if (input_value >= 10 && input_value <=49){
                        //alert("Between 10 - 49");
                        $("#"+current_price).text("$7.46"); //If between 50 and 99 adjust rate

                    } else if (input_value >= 50 && input_value <=99){
                        //alert("Between 50 - 99");
                        $("#"+current_price).text("$5.97"); //If between 50 and 99 adjust rate

                    } else if (input_value >= 100 ){
                        //alert("Over 100");
                        $("#"+current_price).text("$5.47"); //If over 100 adjust rate
                    } else{

                    }

                });

            }

            /* ADDITION FOR VARIABLE DISCOUNTS - END */


            // bind the recalc function to the quantity fields
            $("input[name^=qty_item_]").bind("keyup", recalc);
            // run the calculation function now
            recalc();

            // automatically update the "#totalSum" field every time
            // the values are changes via the keyup event
            $("input[name^=sum]").sum("keyup", "#totalSum");

            // automatically update the "#totalAvg" field every time
            // the values are changes via the keyup event
            $("input[name^=avg]").avg({
                bind:"keyup"
                , selector: "#totalAvg"
                // if an invalid character is found, change the background color
                , onParseError: function(){
                    this.css("backgroundColor", "#cc0000")
                }
                // if the error has been cleared, reset the bgcolor
                , onParseClear: function (){
                    this.css("backgroundColor", "");
                }
            });

            // automatically update the "#minNumber" field every time
            // the values are changes via the keyup event
            $("input[name^=min]").min("keyup", "#numberMin");

            // automatically update the "#minNumber" field every time
            // the values are changes via the keyup event
            $("input[name^=max]").max("keyup", {
                selector: "#numberMax"
                , oncalc: function (value, options){
                    // you can use this to format the value
                    $(options.selector).val(value);
                }
            });

            // this calculates the sum for some text nodes
            $("#idTotalTextSum").click(
                function (){
                    // get the sum of the elements
                    var sum = $(".textSum").sum();

                    // update the total
                    $("#totalTextSum").text("$" + sum.toString());
                }
            );

            // this calculates the average for some text nodes
            $("#idTotalTextAvg").click(
                function (){
                    // get the average of the elements
                    var avg = $(".textAvg").avg();

                    // update the total
                    $("#totalTextAvg").text(avg.toString());
                }
            );
        }
    );

    function recalc(){
        $("[id^=total_item]").calc(
            // the equation to use for the calculation
            "qty * price",
            // define the variables used in the equation, these can be a jQuery object
            {
                qty: $("input[name^=qty_item_]"),
                price: $("[id^=price_item_]")
            },
            // define the formatting callback, the results of the calculation are passed to this function
            function (s){
                // return the number as a dollar amount
                return "$" + s.toFixed(2);
            },
            // define the finish callback, this runs after the calculation has been complete
            function ($this){
                // sum the total of the $("[id^=total_item]") selector
                var sum = $this.sum();


                $("#grandTotal").text(
                //$("#grandTotal").text(
                //$("input[name^=grandTotal]").text(

                    // round the results to 2 digits
                    "$" + sum.toFixed(2)

                );
            }


        );

    }

    function test()
    {
        //Stores the grandtotal to var g_total
        var g_total = $("#grandTotal").text();    




        //Reforats..   $496.00  -->  496
        // Makes it workable
        var myArray = g_total.split('$');
        var myNewArray = myArray[1].split('.');


        //Submits the value to the #this works on line 391
        $('#thisworks').val(myNewArray[0]);

    }

    </script>
```

Comment: `.toFixed(2)` actually means the number should have 2 decimal places: 19.99

Comment: hmm.. thanks for the quick reply. maybe it is from this then?


function test()
 {
  //Stores the grandtotal to var g_total
  var g_total = $("#grandTotal").text();    


  

  //Reforats..   $496.00  -->  496
  // Makes it workable
  var myArray = g_total.split('$');
  var myNewArray = myArray[1].split('.');
 
  
  //Submits the value to the #this works on line 391
  $('#thisworks').val(myNewArray[0]);

 }

Comment: The only thing that I would think would be causing such an effect would be `parseInt`, do you see that anywhere in your code? That `split('.')` could be causing it, that would cause your string to be converted to an array with the first element being "19", and the second being "99". Can you post that formatted properly to your question?

Comment: `$('#thisworks').val(myNewArray[0]);` just gets the part before the decimal point. Is that the value that you're complaining about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var myNewArray = myArray[1].split('.');` is going to create an array like this:

```
myArray = ["19", "99"];
```

if you want it to return 19.99 you could change:

```
$('#thisworks').val(myNewArray[0]);
```

to:

```
$('#thisworks').val(myNewArray.join('.'));
```

Or you could just use the value before it gets split:

```
$('#thisworks').val(myArray[1]);
```

I'm not sure if these are the best solutions, but it should make it work.

Comment: Why even bother splitting if it's just going to be joined again?

Comment: Good question, like I was saying, might not be the best solution, just going for a quick fix.

Comment: that did solve the problem, agree not sure if it is the best solution but it does work.